# How to get Count of child nodes using XPATH for XML

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

i have an XML file with multiple nodes as below :

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<bookstore>

<book category="cooking">
  <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
  <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
  <year>2005</year>
  <price>30.00</price>
</book>

<book category="eating">
   <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
   <author>Giada</author>
   <year>2015</year>
</book>

</bookstore>
```

i want the count of child node in book with category cooking using XPATH .

like for the above example the count of child node with attribute cooking is 4

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try this:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(/bookstore/book[@category = 'cooking']/*)"/>
```